# Xcode 7.0 Beta (7A121I) 'SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reachability

I am getting the following errors in Reachability.h. I added the framework for both extensions. I also tried to re-install Xcode (solution from [here](http://goo.gl/bDXvhC)), but it didn't work.

This project was made in Xcode 6.3.2, and I am trying to use it on Xcode 7.0.

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I can't. It seems that this is not supported yet. I am using the other way to check network status.